# Weird border-width behaviour in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, behavior

My Chrome(v. 33.0.1750.152) is acting really weird with border width of some inputs.

Here's a Codepen demonstrating it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dkadl.

I added the `Increase margin..` and `Decrease margin..` buttons to make it easier to see (click them to change `margin-bottom` property accordingly).

The `margin-bottom` property of `.user-inputs` seems to be affecting the `border-width` of my inputs as well as blurring other elements. I've only been able to see this bug in Chrome.

What's wrong?

edit: This is how it looks like for me: 
[image: Default view]
[image: Added 2px to margin-bottom]
As you can see, elements get really blurry and the border-width of some elements is increased..

Comment: on windows and latest chrome, there is no difference except the margin itself, Border-width is not changing at all for me, Are you using mac

Comment: now I see the problem, it is same here,

Comment: can you remove border:0 than apply border-top border-left and border right for each side except bottom, I changed it and now it is not like that

Comment: still getting error and the problem can be because of chrome but there must be way to fix it

Comment: I think you need to reset this [I tried it but could not solve it I will check for it later]input, input[type="password"], input[type="search"], isindex

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the Translate 50%, on margins where it is not an integer (partial pixel), it makes the content blurry.

As answered on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109299/css-transform-translate-50-50-makes-texts-blurry), add these to your #login-section block:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
```

See updated [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrNVdo)