# CSS: transform: translate(-50%, -50%) makes texts blurry

Tags: css, text, transform, blurry

I want to center my `div` and I use this method, but it makes my texts inside the `div` blurry:

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

#div {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

is there any way to center my `div`?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Good question, and I don't consider it a duplicate.

Comment: this isn't a duplicate guyz!

Comment: I am curious, too. Centering with top + transform: translate would be a great solution in many cases, but this prevents from using it. Blurry texts, hover transitions are broken and some elements have bad positioning inside transformed elements. Clearly a bug for me (Chrome only).

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: Seems in current Chrome ew haven't that issue, right?

Comment: This issue is still there in the latest Chrome - but it's not there in Firefox! That's a little funny.

Comment: You can use flexbox nowadays, which will prevent this issue.

Answer (score 10):

Add these styles around elements blocks which you are translating to fix the anti-aliasing, Translate Z-axis to have a zero value.

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: Use `transfom: scale(2); zoom: 0.5` if nothing works. Worked for me!

Comment: This helped me! Thanks.

Comment: @KushagraGour while `transfom: scale(2); zoom: 0.5` seems to work - if you use JS `getBoundingClientRect()` > it'll result in **wrong calculations**.

Comment: zoom is not a valid CSS property

Comment: One can't use `transform: scale(2);` without overwriting `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` and thus making it not translated...

Comment: @Akerus You can use matrix

Comment: I just had to use `zoom: 1.02` and it looked normal again.

Comment: @Black yes, that can make it better. But value is depends on browser width. So... it's not a fix while you can be sure which value actually helps user.

Comment: @kelegorm, yes, it actually does not really work always.

Comment: I played a little bit with `zoom` and figured out `zoom:1.04;` is working in my case.