# Force div to have an even width and height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have blurry text when using `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to center an absolutely positioned div on my screen.

I have tried *tons* of different solutions ([mostly from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109299/css-transform-translate-50-50-makes-texts-blurry) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411361/webkit-based-blurry-distorted-text-post-animation-via-translate3d)) and *nothing* works except making the width and height of the div an even number.

That is, if the height is 77px instead of 76px then the inner text is blurry. Likewise if the div width is 163 px instead of 162 px then it's blurry.

Is there a way to ensure the width and height of a dynamic div is an even number?

Using JavaScript seems like a no-go because not only is it complex but it would cause the element to flash to a different width immediately after being rendered (need to render it to first find out the width) which is unpleasant for the user to see.

Also, I can't just hardcode the width and height because the contents are dynamic. Also, if I could hardcode the width to, say, 100px, then I wouldn't even need this issue, because I could just do something like `transform: translate(calc(-50% - 50px),-50%);` to sidestep the issue.

Here's a code example:

```css
.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 25px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Inter;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <b> asdf </b> blurrya
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered a different approach to centering your div? Tried flexbox?

Comment: It's absolutely positioned on the screen so I cannot use flexbox. That is, it's not a part of the document flow and should be rendered on top of them.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps but sure I'll add one. One second

Comment: In terms of the flashing when setting dimensions using JavaScript - could you start the element as visibility: hidden and show it once you have sized it?

Comment: @patrickb I suppose that's possible, but that seems like quite the mess to have to do just to get this to work (start off invisible, measure, calculate width and height, potentially increment by 1, and then show)

Comment: But do you have to use absolute position for the child element, or are you just doing that so that you can vertically and horizontally center it?

Comment: Yeah I don't see how I would do it without absolute positioning. The entire element is a short-lived notification that fades away and it is not a part of the regular document flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to add one more element you can use `flex` within the absolutely positioned element to center the inner most element while maintaining its exclusion from the document flow.

```css
.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;  
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.center {
    top: 25px;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Inter;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p class="center">
      <b>asdf </b> blurrya
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured it'd have to be something like this. Alright, fair enough. Thanks